# How to use StreamingResponseBody and try-with-resources?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi, try-with-resources, autocloseable

I'd like to create an Excel sheet dynamically and return that to the client. I'd like to use the `StreamingResponseBody` as the return type in order to save some RAM. I'm also using `try-with-resources` to close the `workbook` automatically. Here is the code.

```java
@RestController
public class ExcelController {

  @GetMapping("/hello")
  public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> excel() throws IOException {
    try (var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();) {
      workbook.createSheet("hello world");
      return ResponseEntity.ok()
          .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
          .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=data.xlsx")
          .body(workbook::write);
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work and I'm getting the following error message.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.io.IOException: Cannot write data, document seems to have been closed already
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:215) ~[poi-ooxml-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:111) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:98) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startCallableProcessing$4(WebAsyncManager.java:337) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I already tried using my custom TaskExecutor as described by `StreamingResponseBody` but that didn't really help. In the end I found a solution that works but I'm wondering why the first solution including `try-with-resources` and method reference does not work.

```java
@RestController
public class ExcelController {

  @GetMapping("/hello")
  public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> excel() throws IOException {
    var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    workbook.createSheet("hello world");
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=data.xlsx")
        .body(
            out -> {
              workbook.write(out);
              workbook.close();
            });
  }
}
```

I highly appreciate your help! Thank you

Comment: Use the try-with-resource inside the `StreamingResponseBody`.

Comment: That works indeed, thank you! The syntax is not as nice but that's ok :) Do you want to add the solution as a proper answer? I will accept it.

Comment: StreamingResponseBody is async so the .body call is called when needed by the ResponseEntity - this can happen after the try-with-resource wrapping the XSSFWorkbook completes (think of this as happening in 2 different threads) - see async mentioned in https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.16.RELEASE_to_5.0.17.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%205.0.17.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/StreamingResponseBody.html

Comment: I think what @M.Deinum is suggesting is that you do all the XSSF Work in the body call (create the XSSFWorkbook, set it up and then write to outputStream) - create a method that does the takes an outputStream as a method param and include all the XSSF code with your try-with-resources in the method and then have .body call that method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `StreamingResponseBody` works async and as your try-with-resources is outside of that part it might be that the resource is already closed (I would suspect in 99.9% of the cases?). To fix do all that stuff inside the `StreamingResponseBody`.

```java
return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=data.xlsx")
    .body(
        out -> {
          try (var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            workbook.createSheet("hello world");
            workbook.write(out);
          }
      });
}
```

To make it a bit more readable (and the fact that I don't like multiline lambdas) you can ofcourse also move that code to a method and call that from your lambda.

```java
private void writeWorkbook(OutputStream out) {
  try (var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
    workbook.createSheet("hello world");
    workbook.write(out);
  }
}

return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=data.xlsx")
    .body( this::writeWorkbook);
}
```

This will open (and close) the `Workbook` at the proper time.